# Filter hidden files in webkitdirectory?

Tags: html, file-upload, webkit, hidden-files

On uploading folder using webkitdirectory in HTML, hidden files are also uploaded. Is there a way to filter the hidden files?

Here I have uploaded a folder with one file and four hidden files:

[image]

How to get only non hidden files on upload using webkitdirectory in HTML?